# Raspberry Pi Motion-Mmal: I want to disable live stream capabilities

Tags: raspberry-pi, live-streaming, raspbian, motion

I have a few questions about Motion-MMAL for the Raspberry Pi B+ model, running on Raspbian: Sorry if these are noob questions.

1) I want to disable the live stream capability completely; however, i can only find information on how to keep the live stream local

2) If I do not visit the local address for the live stream, is it still technically uploading data and live streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you comment out the webcam_port value in motion.conf then you will not be streaming.  Default is 0 for disabled.

So motion will still be recording video if there is actual motion.  Nobody will be able to view a live stream.